# Executing powershell threads in IIS as impersonated user

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, iis, impersonation

I've been working on a web application that makes use of Powershell scripts. For some reason, even with ASP.NET impersonation, I am getting "access denied" errors on commands that require elevated access.

The web application is deployed via IIS 7.5 running on a Windows 2008 R2 Standard SP1 Server.

I've checked the exception logged in event viewer and noticed that account being used in the spawned thread is the NETWORK SERVICE account :

[image: Network Service Exception]

From what I can tell, this means that impersonation is not being carried to powershell cmdlet threads. I am confident that the user to be impersonated should have access to run the script but it looks like the permissions being used are those of the NETWORK SERVICE account which is not the goal.

I've also made the following changes to the aspnet.config file as suggested in a few articles I've read to no avail:

```
       <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
       <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

Here's a snippet of the ASP NET C# code to help explain my situation:

```
            //Create Runspace
            RunspaceConfiguration psConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            Runspace psRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(psConfig);

            //Configure runspace to run on the current thread
            psRunspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
            psRunspace.ThreadOptions = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;

            using (Pipeline psPipeline = psRunspace.CreatePipeline())
            {
                psRunspace.Open();
                psPipeline.Commands.AddScript("C:\\Scripts\\Powershell\\MyScript.ps1");

                // Invoke the cmdlet

                var results = psPipeline.Invoke();
                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var psObject in results)
                {
                    // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
                    // Add \r\n for line breaks
                    builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }
                //Display the results
                ResultBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

I have spent the last 5 hours getting this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As far as i understand you can only use Impersonation for authentication. Not authorization as you are going for.

Comment: @Jower thanks for the reply. Let me see what I can dig up on authorization. So, in that situation, is there no way to do this without hard coding credentials? A number of users will be using the tool so it's adamant that their accounts be used for any elevated actions so we can log any and all actions made. (e.g. creating and AD account)

Comment: I would appreciate it if someone can confirm if this is even possible? I hope I'm not barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: @Yad hello Yad, did you find any solution so far?

Answer (score 1):

please try following solution - it works for me in a SharePoint environment

```
public ListUsersPS(string searchstring)
{
....
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;

ctx = identity.Impersonate();

Runspaceconfiguration connectionInfo = Runspaceconfiguration.Create();
...
using (Runspace rsp = Runspacefactory.Createrunspace(connectionInfo))
{
...
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by changing the user running your IIS process?

In IIS you are able to change the user running your application pool. Be carefull if multiple application use the same application pool.

To change the user running your application pool in IIS, click on Advanced settings, there is a section called Process Model and Identity.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that several users will be logging into the web application. This simply changes the accounts running the application, not impersonate the users logging in. Appreciate your reply though.